# Azure Storage Rest API Speed and Bandwidth Requirement

Tags: azure, azure-storage

Is there an approach to calculate the internet bandwidth requirement when transferring data into Azure Blob storage (Append Blob) using the Storage Rest api.

For instance if I want to upload 50MB using the storage API into an Azure Storage account is there a model/approach to determine the number of hours that the upload process will use based on the internet bandwidth connectivity and the limitation of Rest API (which will split the 50mb into a maximum of 4MIB chunks)?
Forgive me is this is a broad question

Comment: which api are you using?

Comment: @IvanYang The Azure storage Rest API will be used

Comment: are you directly using the rest api, or use the sdk? and it's better that you can provide a link to the api or sdk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to do that.

What we can do is that monitor the upload/download progress, and you may calculate them by yourself.

Not sure which api you're using, but if you're using [the latest blob storage sdk](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Storage.Blobs), you can follow [this article](https://www.craftedforeveryone.com/upload-or-download-file-from-azure-blob-storage-with-progress-percentage-csharp/) to monitor the progress.

Or you can use [Microsoft Azure Storage Data Movement Library](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net-data-movement), you can follow [this page](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net-data-movement#upload-a-blob) to monitor the progress.

Comment: @user989865, if the answer is helpful, could you please accept it as answer?